# Best workaround to create a PHP class constant from an expression?

Tags: php, class, constants

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```php
class Circle {

    const RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE = M_PI * 2;  // Not allowed

    private $radius;

    public function __construct( $radius ) {
        $this->radius = $radius;
    }

    ...

    public function getCircumference() {
        return $this->radius * self::RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE;
    }

}
```

But I can't create a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) from an expression like that:

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

So my question is: What's the best workaround for this limitation of PHP?  I'm aware of the following workarounds, but are there any others which are better?

### 1. Create a property

```php
class Circle {

    private static $RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE;

    private $radius;

    public function __construct( $radius ) {
        $this->radius = $radius;
        $this->RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE = M_PI * 2;
    }

    ...

    public function getCircumference() {
        return $this->radius * $this->RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE;
    }

}
```

I don't like this, because the value of `$RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE` can be changed, so it's not really a "constant".

### 2. Use `define()`

```php
define( 'RAD_TO_CIRCUM', M_PI * 2 );

class Circle {

    const RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE = RAD_TO_CIRCUM;

    ...

    public function getCircumference() {
        return $this->radius * self::RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE;
    }

}
```

This is better, since the value is truly constant, but the drawback is that `RAD_TO_CIRCUM` has been globally defined.

**A digression**

I don't understand how this can work. *(Edit: I've tested it, and it does work.)* According to the [Handbook of PHP Syntax](http://www.pvtuts.com/php/php-static#const-define):

> The `const` modifier creates a compile-time constant and so the compiler will replace all usage of the constant with its value. In contrast, `define` creates a run-time constant which is not set until run-time. This is the reason why `define` constants may be assigned with expressional values, whereas `const` requires constant values which are known at compile-time.

The manual [confirms](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) that "constants defined using the `const` keyword ... are defined at compile-time".

In [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51765) from 3 years ago, a member of the PHP team wrote:

> For the class constant we need a constant value at compile time and can't evaluate expressions. `define()` is a regular function, evaluated at run time and can therefore contain any value of any form.

But in my example above, the value of `RAD_TO_CIRCUM` is not known at compile-time. So what is the compiler putting for the value of `RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE`?

I'm guessing that the compiler creates some kind of placeholder for the value of `RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE`, and at run-time, that placeholder gets replaced with the value of `RAD_TO_CIRCUM`. Might this placeholder be a kind of [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)? If so, maybe this technique should be avoided? The manual [says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php): "It is possible to define constants as a resource, but it should be avoided, as it can cause unexpected results."

### 3. Create a method

```php
class Circle {

    ...

    private static function RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE() {
        return M_PI * 2;
    }

    public function getCircumference() {
        return $this->radius * $this->RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE();
    }

}
```

This is my favourite workaround that I'm aware of. The value is constant, and it doesn't affect the global space.

Is there another workaround which is even better?

Comment: Hmmm forget my answer, it's totally stupid. x) Can't modify a const value, that's the purpose of it...

Comment: Btw solution 2) won't work. define() is runtime while const is "compile" time (i.e done before).

Comment: Why bother about global scope? `M_PI` is global as well.

Comment: Also, ask yourself if you really need this as a constant. Returning `$this->radius * M_PI * 2` might be more readable. Let PHP worry about any optimizations.

Comment: @Virus721 I know `const` is done before `define()` – see my "digression". Solution #2 *shouldn't* work, but it does (I've tested it), and I'd like to know *why* it works.

Comment: That's beyond my understand of PHP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of PHP 5.6, you can use [math expressions in PHP constants](http://php.net/migration56.new-features#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs), so this would work:

```
const RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE = M_PI * 2;
```

I encountered this thread because my environment wasn't configured properly (was set to PHP 5.4 by accident), so don't forget to check your PHP version.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this approach:

```
class Circle {

    ...

    private function RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE() {
        static $RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE;

        if ( null === $RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE )
            $RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE = M_PI * 2;

        return $RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE;
    }

    public function getCircumference() {
        return $this->radius * $this->RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE();
    }
}
```

The goal is calculation only once for all class entities, like a real constant.

Comment: This not needed since PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

my installed php version is 7.1 but, in my IDE(PhpStorm) settings my php version 5.4 was selected. Once i've changed my php version the problem was gone.

PhpStorm settings->PHP and change the PHP language level and CLI interpreter php version.

Answer (score 0):

I still have to use PHP 5.3 in one project (not something I can control) and have to cope with similar problems.

In your case you could define the constant externally (and it seems legit)

```
define('TWO_PI',PI*2);

class Circle
{
    const RADIUS_TO_CIRCUMFERENCE = TWO_PI;
...
```

This seems to work fine even in PHP 5.3. The cleanest approach is the method one but slightly slower.

Answer (score -1):

If you agree to use a standard variable instead of const keyword :

```
class Foo {

    public $CONST_A; // = calculation A // To let people quickly see the value.
    public $CONST_B; // = calculation B 

    public static function initClass() {
        self::$CONST_A = /* calculation A */;
        self::$CONST_B = /* calculation B */;
    }
}

Foo::initClass();
```

`initClass()` is done only once, when the class file is required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't help me. Firstly, the properties `$CONST_A` and `$CONST_B` need to be `public static` for the code to work. Your answer has the same problem as my solution #1 (the values of the properties can be changed, and so it's not a good workaround for creating "constants"). In addition, since the properties are `public`, anyone can change their values from outside the class, by doing something like `Foo::$CONST_A = 10;`.