# how to define a constant member of a class with $_SERVER superglobals?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
class View
{
   const DEFAULT_VIEWS_DIRECTORY =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "views/";
}
```

but, it gives me syntax error

> Parse error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\View.class.php on line 17

I checked the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) and it says

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, or a function call.

**is there any work around to do what I want ?**, because I consume this value in the class heavily, and having this as a constant will make the class more pretty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, Expression is not allowed as class constant value, but it doesn't stop you to initiate your default view directory once and and use it on different occasion:

```
class View
{
    private $defaultViewDirectory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->defaultViewDirectory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "views/";
    }

    public function getDefaultViewDirectory()
    {
        return $this->defaultViewDirectory;
    }
}
```

Or you could implement a Singleton pattern like:

```
class View
{
    private $defaultViewDirectory;

    private function initDefaultViewDirectory()
    {
        $this->defaultViewDirectory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "views/";
    }

    public function getDefaultViewDirectory()
    {
        if (is_null($this->defaultViewDirectory)) {
            $this->initDefaultViewDirectory();
        }
        return $this->defaultViewDirectory;
    }
}
```

Or if you need a static access:

```
class StaticView
{
    private static $defaultViewDirectory;

    private static function initDefaultViewDirectory()
    {
        self::$defaultViewDirectory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "views/";
    }

    public static function getDefaultViewDirectory()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$defaultViewDirectory)) {
            self::initDefaultViewDirectory();
        }
        return self::$defaultViewDirectory;
    }
}
```

So you could call `StaticView::getDefaultViewDirectory()`

Comment: thanks. that is helpful. but unfortunately I need to use the constant inside static methods, so an instance variable like you did will not be referable inside the static methods. I up-voted your answer but I can't accept it since it didn't solved my problem. thank you very much for your time.

Comment: fair enough :) thanks for the up-vote, I have update the answer to demonstrate the static access as well ;)

Comment: Actually have a look at [Best workaround to create a PHP class constant from an expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079131/best-workaround-to-create-a-php-class-constant-from-an-expression)

Comment: thanks. looks like php will not let me do it exactly the way I wanted. I know from C language that constants must not have variable data because the compiler needs to know the value to produce the op code. but I thought that php might be flexible in this point since it is parsed at run time(while the variable data is ready). thank you for your time :)