# Constant expressions in PHP 5.5 or before

Tags: php, php-5.4

I'm working on a legacy PHP codebase that runs on PHP 5.4.
I want to derive class-specific constants or properties based on a common constant. So for instance in PHP 5.6 or later I'd do:

**config.php**

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', 'PATH_TO_CONFIG_DIR');
```

**MyClass.php**

```
class MyClass {
     const FILE_A = CONFIG_DIR . '/fileA';
     const FILE_B = CONFIG_DIR . '/fileB';
}
```

But constant expressions are only allowed since PHP 5.6.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

So in PHP 5.4 what are the options that I could follow to derive sub-values based on a common constant within the class?

Comment: how about using `$GLOBALS`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: or just pass the variables to the constructor of the class.

Comment: @Raptor Thanks for the suggestions. But in that case I can't define those new variables as constants though.

Comment: Correct. You are right.

Comment: Ok for now but please upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: Strange that the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079131/best-workaround-to-create-a-php-class-constant-from-an-expression) seems to give all the options in the question, not sure if that could be reworked to a proper reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`define` could be an option.

```
define('CONFIG_DIR', 'PATH_TO_CONFIG_DIR');
define('CONFIG_DIR_FILE_A', CONFIG_DIR . '/fileA');
define('CONFIG_DIR_FILE_B', CONFIG_DIR . '/fileB');
class MyClass {
     const FILE_A = CONFIG_DIR_FILE_A;
     const FILE_B = CONFIG_DIR_FILE_B;
}
```

Comment: To obtain the constant `FILE_A` from `MyClass`, [Relection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) can be used in PHP 5.4: `$c = new ReflectionClass('MyClass'); echo $c->getConstants()['FILE_A'];`